# Outlook 2016 Web Add in Desktop

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, yo

I have created a project for an outlook web add-in.  I can see the web add-in in the browser UI, and click everything appears to be correct.

However I cannot view it on the desk top version of outlook 2016.  The directions say:

```
 1. Open the Office Store, either in Outlook 2016 for Windows or Outlook on the web:

    - In Outlook 2016 for Windows, choose the Store button on the Home tab.

    - In Outlook on the web, choose the gear icon in the upper-right corner, then choose Manage integrations.

2. Click the text Click here to add a custom add-in.

3. Choose Add from file....

4. Browse to and select the tw-email-manifest.xml file from the root of the project folder, and then choose Open.

5. Review the warning prompt and choose Install.

6. Close the Office Store window. Your add-in will load in Outlook.
```

Followed the directions for Outlook on the web but when I get to **In Outlook 2016 for Windows, choose the Store button on the Home tab.** it directs me to the Office 365 Link https://store.office.com/en-us/appshome.aspx?productgroup=Outlook&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Anybody with ideas.  When I use a default setup project out of VS 2017 everything runs fine, but attempting to create the project using Microsoft Office Add-in Project Generator - YO OFFICE!  It will not have a MVC back end.

The direction came from this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on how to sideload in Outlook 2016 desktop are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#sideload-an-add-in-in-outlook-on-the-desktop)

If this doesn't work for you, you can still sideload from Outlook on the Web

Comment: Unfortunately, I get to step 3 and I do not see Click Here to Add Custom Link and missing a security setting that would show that.  Under category I get All than Best Apps of the Year

Comment: I can test and am continuing to develop using the web based one but that does not allow for testing the desktop or mobile version of my application.

Comment: If you have sideloaded via Outlook on the Web, and your add-in is supported in Outlook 2016, and formatted correctly for Outlook mobile, then you should still see your add-in in both desktop and mobile clients.

Comment: Sorry, what I did in an attempt to get around this is create a project using the standard Visual Studio 2017 project template.  I tested this by running it first and verifiying that I can see the basic example that is created.  I had success with that protion. instead of using ~remoteAppUrl in the Manifest XML is used https://localhost:3000

Comment: Sorry, What I did to test is create a project using the standard Visual Studio 2017 project template.  I ran it first and verified the basic example works.  I had success.  I than changed the manifest to instead of using ~remoteAppUrl in the XML to use https://localhost:3000 and ran it.  Again I was able to see the plugin in the web version of outlook just fine,   I go to the desktop and I get the menu item and My Add-in Group -> Display all Properties click and I get an error message: ADD-IN-ERROR Sorry we can't load the add-in.  Please make sure you have network and etc.